# understanding JuMP in Julia Lang?

Tags: julia, julia-jump

```
using JuMP, Clp
d = [40 60 75 25] # monthly demand for boats
m = Model(with_optimizer(Clp.Optimizer))

@variables(m, begin
0 <= x[1:4] <= 40 #boats produced with regular labor
y[1:4]>= 0 #boats produced with overtime labor
h[1:5] >= 0 #boats held in inventory
end)
@constraint(m, h[1] == 10)
@constraint(m, flow[i in 1:4], h[i]+x[i]+y[i]==d[i]+h[i+1])     # conservation of boats
@objective(m, Min, 400*sum(x) + 450*sum(y) + 20*sum(h))         # minimize costs

status = optimize!(m)
println("Build ", Array{Int64}(value(x')), " using regular labor")
println("Build ", Array{Int64}(value(x')), " using regular labor")
println("Build ", Array{Int64}(value(y')), " using overtime labor")
println("Inventory: ", Array{Int64}(value(h'))
```

I am very new to Julia Language. I am practicing with the code above. But I am getting an error which I don't seem to understand. The error is:

```
ERROR: LoadError: `JuMP.value` is not defined for collections of JuMP types. Use Julia's broadcast syntax instead: `JuMP.value.(x)`.
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String) at ./error.jl:33
 [2] value(::LinearAlgebra.Adjoint{VariableRef,Array{VariableRef,1}}) at /Users/pst/.julia/packages/JuMP/MsUSY/src/variables.jl:832
 [3] top-level scope at none:0
 [4] include at ./boot.jl:317 [inlined]
 [5] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1044
 [6] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:29
 [7] exec_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:266
 [8] _start() at ./client.jl:425
in expression starting at /Users/pst/Optimization/sailcovar1.jl:22.
```

Please help me out. Thanks

Comment: The error message really gave you the answer already: "Use Julia's broadcast syntax instead: `JuMP.value.(x)`".

Answer (score 2):

In order to apply a scalar function (like `Jump.value`) to a vector or array, you need to use the [dot notation for broadcasting](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#man-vectorized-1). So you need to replace all of your `value(...)` calls with `value.(...)`.